# Can I hide referrer via double 301 redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-referer

If I have a domain "A" and it redirects users to domain "B" that redirects the user to site "C" via 301 then will the site "C" see that the traffic was originally from domain "A" or will it only see the domain "B" as referral?

I want to hide that traffic is coming from domain "A".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Site C can know about site A while site B is a 301 redirect since many browsers overlook the referent of the redirecting site.